# Is it possible to convert an OSL script to Blender nodes? If so, how?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, osl

The question is quite open, with a fundamental question, the OSL nodes are fantastic, but they have a great limitation, the fact that they don't work with "GPU" type renderings and moreover it doesn't seem to work at all on Eevee render.
So I was wondering if it was possible somehow (Maybe with the help of some makeup)
Convert an OSL node script to a blender node / nodes.
This is a question to be directed to better research on the subject.

Comment: Some, you can. One thing you can do in OSL that you can't, in nodes, is cast your own probing rays for sampling the scene in some way, If your node depends on that, no go.

Comment: Is there any tool that does this, or do you have to study osl well? It looks very complicated

Answer (score 3):

There was an old project that does this:

https://github.com/LazyDodo/oslpy

It is better to wait for an EEVEE GLSL node in future and rewrite the shader in GLSL

Comment: note: if you want to convert a specific shader, it might be done manually, for loops though things have to be repeated manually

Comment: Sounds interesting but sadly this doesn't seem to work very well